# Move file then zip

Tags: php, zip

I am making a php script that moves every file which is at least one year old into a folder, then zips the folder. I have already done the moving of files but I'm having problems with how to turn the result of `time()` into a year so it deletes one year old files. And how do you zip the folder? Here is the code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['archive']))
    {
        $name=time();
        if (mkdir($name))
        {
            $days = 7;
            $source = 'documents/';
            $destination = "$name/";

            // Open the directory
            if ($handle = opendir($source))
            {
                while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
                {

                    if (is_file($source.$file))
                    {

                        if (filemtime($source.$file) < ( time() - ( $days * 24 * 60 * 60 ) ) )
                        {

                            if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file))
                            {
                                unlink($source.$file);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Also how do I show all the zipped folder in a database?

Comment: um ... `$days = 7;` -> `$days = 365;`

Comment: hi yeah but how about the leap year? ive already one the 365 days